# Variables and pattern reading

Tags: javascript

Just started coding a few weeks ago, and a project I'm working on is a somewhat replica of the 'Simon' game (in which leds would light up in a certain pattern and the pattern would have to be inputted back into the game via push buttons)

I've added variables for each button in order to get the pattern part of the code right, but it doesn't seem to be working. Is it something to do with that, or another problem entirely?

```
int ledPins[] = {10,11,12,13,6,7};
const int buttonPin1 = 2;
const int buttonPin2 = 3;
const int buttonPin3 = 4;
const int buttonPin4 = 5;
int digitalVal1 = digitalRead(buttonPin1);
int digitalVal2 = digitalRead(buttonPin2);
int digitalVal3 = digitalRead(buttonPin3);
int digitalVal4 = digitalRead(buttonPin4);
int b1on = false;
int b2on = false;
int b3on = false;
int b4on = false;
int bcount = 0;
int delayTime = 200;
void firstpattern() {
  int delayTime = 200;

  digitalWrite(ledPins[1], HIGH);
  delay(delayTime);

  digitalWrite(ledPins[1], LOW);
  delay(delayTime);

  digitalWrite(ledPins[3], HIGH);
  delay(delayTime);

  digitalWrite(ledPins[3], LOW);
  delay(delayTime);

  digitalWrite(ledPins[2], HIGH);
  delay(delayTime);

  digitalWrite(ledPins[2], LOW);
  delay(delayTime);

  digitalWrite(ledPins[0], HIGH);
  delay(delayTime);

  digitalWrite(ledPins[0], LOW);
  delay(delayTime);


  delay(300);
}

void setup() {

  int index;

  for(index = 0; index <= 4; index ++);

  {
    pinMode(ledPins[index], OUTPUT);
  }

  pinMode(buttonPin1,INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(buttonPin2,INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(buttonPin3,INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(buttonPin4,INPUT_PULLUP);

  firstpattern();



}

void loop() {


  if(HIGH == digitalVal2) {
      if (b2on == false && bcount == 0){
        b4on = false;
        b3on = false;
        b2on = true;
        b1on = false;
        bcount = bcount + 1;
  
  
    }
    else{
  
      digitalWrite(ledPins[4], HIGH);
    }
  }

  if (HIGH == digitalVal4) {
    if (b4on == false && b2on == true && bcount == 1){
      b4on = true;
      b3on = false;
      b2on = false;
      b1on = false;
      bcount = bcount + 1;
    }

    else{
  
      digitalWrite(ledPins[4], HIGH);
    }
  }





  if (HIGH == digitalVal3) {
    if (b3on == false && b4on == true && bcount == 2){
      b3on = true;
      b3on = false;
      b4on = false;
      b1on = false;
      bcount = bcount + 1;
    }
     else{
      
      digitalWrite(ledPins[4], HIGH);
    }
  }
  if (HIGH == digitalVal1) {
    if (b1on == false && b3on == true && bcount == 3){
      b1on = true;
      b3on = false;
      b2on = false;
      b4on = false;
      bcount = bcount + 1;
    }
  
    }
   if (bcount == 4){
    digitalWrite(ledPins[5], HIGH);
   }
    else{
     
      digitalWrite(ledPins[4], HIGH);
    }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be over complicating this a tiny bit.
What you need to do is create an object with an array of turns like such:

```js
var pattern = {
    "red": [1,5],
    "blue": [3],
    "green": [2],
    "yellow": [4]
}
```

where the numerical values is the turns each color was "played" then when the user clicks on the appropriate buttons compare their turn to the turns specified in the object's turn array
for more information look at this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y12eamL8/)

Comment: Could you explain this a bit further? Thanks so much

Comment: updated my answer with a fiddle that should lead you down the right path

Comment: would it be possible for you to do a simplified pattern which i could read and then adapt for mine, im a little confused                                                                          forgot to mention, this is done on arduino ICE, if that were to change anything

Comment: in the end i just added a variable for if each 'turn' had their button pressed correctly and it ended up working :)